# Firebase storage bandwidth used?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase to store some images for my web application. I want to stay in the free tier so I was wondering how can I limit my bandwidth usage.
If I understand correctly:
this:

```
const imageUrl: string = await getDownloadURL(ref(storageRef, `${img.id}.jpg`));
```

and the render:

```
<img src={imageUrl} className='story-img' />
```

counts toward the bandwidth use in Firebase correct? Is it roughly the same? I believe that the render should use more bandwidth(equal to the image size)
Would it reduce my bandwidth usage if I store the IMG URLs obtained by the above method in local storage?

Bonus question: I will have roughly 200 pictures in Firestore all under 500kb could I be in the free tier with 100 users daily?

Comment: Requesting the image URL won't consume significant bandwidth, but downloading the contents of the image from Cloud Storage will. There really isn't much more to it than that.

Comment: download mean the render in an img tag right?

Comment: so its doesnt matter where i get the url (getDownloadURL() function or local storage) aslong as i render with the url of https://firebase....

Comment: To render the image you'll need to download its data, and it's that downloading that Firebase counts as bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @FrankvanPuffelen already mentioned in his comment, only requesting the URL will not consume much, as it's only a URL. It will consume maybe tens of bytes. However, downloading the image itself will consume bandwidth.

So if you display (render) the image on the screen, that means that you need to download the image which indeed consumes bandwidth.

There are two ways in which you can decrease the amount of data you download. The first one would be to use a Firebase Extension called [Resize Images](https://extensions.dev/extensions/firebase/storage-resize-images) to resize the images at reasonable resolution. That means that doesn't matter how big the picture is uploaded, you'll always resize it so it occupies less space.

The second option would be, to cache the data. That means you only download the image once. The second time when you render it, you'll read the image from the cache.